# Predefined subject and body in EmailComposer

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is there any way to predefine body and subject of email in emailcomposer ios phonegap plugin? So far i found some group in google groups

```
window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposer("My Subject","My Plain Text Body", "recip...@email.com,recipient2@email.com", "ccReci...@email.com,ccRecipient2@email.com", "bccRec...@email.com,bccRecipient2@email.com",false);
```

but i'm not sure how to connect that to my html page. I tried

```
cordova.exec(null, null, "EmailComposer", "showEmailComposer", [args]);
```

in my js file, but that shows emailcomposer page, which is unacceptable. How do i make user enter only email or recipient?

UPD: I didnt look into emailcomposer.js, there is array [args], where i can define everything i need, but i'm not sure how to do that
Tried this way, but that didnt help

```
var args = [toRecipients="example@email.com"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Added params as hash

```
args['subject']='hello world';
```

and in your index file initialize hash with name args

```
args = {};
```